# Is expression and its result is the same thing?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

So, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $0.5$ are just two different ways to address the same object which is rational number $\frac{1}{2}$.

What about more complex expressions? Like $\{a, b\} \cap \{b, c\}$ is just the other way to address set $\{b\}$? Or is $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is just a number $1$? Or is $1 + 2$ is just another way to write number $3$ and $3$ is just another way to write expression $1 + 2$?

So, Is expression and its result is the same thing?

Or little more general question: is it valid to say that an expression and all other expressions which I can get from it by applying valid operations are just different ways to address same mathematical object? Or is there a sufficient differences between writing an expression and writing an object that you can get by evaluating it in more direct way?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Would [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) be a good place for your question?

Comment: I suppose that it depends on what you mean by *same*. As numbers and as sets, yes, these various expressions describe the same object. But maybe in some context you're interested in a more granular description of mathematical expressions, in which case you can distinguish some of these. This is a deep topic. See, e.g., [these](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equality) [three](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence) [pages](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) in the nLab.

Comment: If a = c and a ≠ b, then {a,b} ∩ {b,c}  ≠ {b}, contrary to what you wrote.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf)

Comment: The expressions "3" and "1+2" refer to the same real number, but neither of them *is* that number.

Comment: *expressions* (numerals, formulas) are linguistic entities that refer to "things" and facts, like words and statements of ordinary language.